# Quadtree object movement

Tags: quadtree

So I need some help brainstorming, from a theoretical standpoint. Right now I have some code that just draws some objects. The objects lie in the leaves of a quadtree. Now as the objects move I want to keep them placed in the correct leaf of the quadtree.

Right now I am just reconstructing the quadtree on the objects after I change their position. I was trying to figure out a way to correct the tree without rebuilding it completely. All I can think of is having a bunch of pointers to adjacent leaf nodes.

Does anyone have an idea of how to figure out the node into which an object moves without just having a ton of pointers everywhere or a link to articles on this? All I could find was different ways to build the quadtree, nothing about updating it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question.  You want some way of mapping between spatial coordinates and leaves on the quadtree.

Here's one possible solution I've been looking at:

For simplicity, let's do the 1D case first.  And lets assume we have 32 gridpoints in x.  Every grid point then corresponds to some leaf on a quadtree of depth five.  (depth 0 = the whole grid, depth 1 = 2 points, depth 2 = 4 points... depth 5 = 32 points).

Each leaf could be represented by the branch indices leading to the leaf.  At each level there are two branches we can label A and B.  So, a particular leaf might be labeled BBAAB, which would mean, go down the B branch, then the B branch, then the A branch, then the B branch and then the B branch.

So, how do you map e.g. BBABB to an x grid point between 0..31?  Just convert it to binary, so that BBABB->11011 = 27.  Thus, the mapping from gridpoint to leaf-node is simply a matter of translating the letters A and B into 0s and 1s and then interpreting the result as a binary number.

For the 2D case, it's only slightly more complicated.  Now we have four branches from each node, so we can label each branch path using a four-letter alphabet, e.g. starting from the root and taking the 3rd branch and then the fourth branch and then the first branch and then the second branch and then the second branch again we would generate the string CDABB.

Now to convert the string (e.g. 'CDABB') into a pair of gridvalues (x,y).

Let's assume A is lower-left, B is lower right, C is upper left and D is upper right.  Then, symbolically, we could write, A.x=0, A.y=0 / B.x=1, B.y=0 / C.x=0, C.y=1 / D.x=1, D.y=1.

Taking the example CDABB, we first look at its x values (CDABB).x = (01011), which gives us the x grid point.  And similarly for y.

Finally, if you want to find out e.g. the node immediately to the right of CDABB, then simply convert it to a pair of binary numbers in x and y, add +1 to the x value and convert the new pair of binary numbers back into a string.

I'm sure this has all been discovered, but I haven't yet found this information on the web.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the spatial data necessary to insert an element into the quad-tree in the first place (ex: its point or rectangle), then you have the same data needed to remove it.

An easy way is before you move an element, remove it from the quad-tree using the same data you used to originally insert it, then move it, then re-insert.

Removal from the quad-tree can first remove the element from the leaf node(s), then if the leaf nodes become empty, remove them from their parents. If the parents become empty, remove them from their parents, and so forth.

This simple method is efficient enough for a complex world of objects moving every frame as long as you implement the quad-tree efficiently (ex: use a free list for the nodes). There shouldn't have to be a heap allocation on a per-node basis to insert it, nor a heap deallocation involved in removing every single node. Most node allocations/deallocations should be a simple constant-time operation just involving, say, the manipulation of a couple of integers or pointers.

You can also make this a little more complex if you like. You can start off storing the previous position of an object and then move it. If the new position occupies nodes other than the previous position, then remove the object from the nodes it no longer occupies and insert it to the new ones. Otherwise just keep it in the same node(s).

**Update**

I usually try to avoid linking my previous answers, but in this case I ended up doing a pretty comprehensive write up on the topic which would be hard to replicate anywhere else. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48330314/4842163